# how to write conditional values in pullRelated query in dot cms?

Tags: dotcms

Hi I have  content type like PartGroup and PartNumber, I want to filter behalf PartNumber column value, I have written a query like below. I have applied partnumber value with column name it's not working can any one help me.

#set($partNumbers = $dotcontent.pullRelated('PartGroup-PartNumber', ${pgroupF.identifier},"PartNumber.searchableSpecifications:(+\"Cable!_Type|belden!_735a,!_bt3002,!_tzc75024\" )", false, 0))

Thanks
Santosh

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you're using to call the method is correct, but it looks like the syntax of your query isn't correct.  The query in the pullRelated method uses Lucene syntax.

Since I don't know the format of the data field you're searching, it's a little hard to tell what you want the condition to do.  But I'm guessing from your example that you're trying to use commas as "OR" operators, and that the field you're trying to search is a large text field that may have multiple different values in it.

In Lucene you need to use spaces rather than commas for an "OR" operator.  You also shouldn't need the escaped double quotes in your query, but you will probably need wildcards surrounding the values you want to match.  And I'm not sure what the exclamation marks are for, but in Lucene the exclamation mark is a "NOT" operator.

So I'm guessing your query should look something like this (but again, it's dependent on the format of your data, so without seeing what some of the data looks like, this is just a guess):

`"+PartNumber.searchableSpecifications:(*Cable_Type:belden_735a* *Cable_Type:_bt3002* *Cable_Type_tzc75024*)"`

If you're using the exclamation marks to try and match any cable **except** the ones you have listed in the query, then you're query would look like this instead:

`"-PartNumber.searchableSpecifications:(*Cable_Type:belden_735a* *Cable_Type:_bt3002* *Cable_Type_tzc75024*)"`

For more information on how Lucene syntax works (as well as examples), see the query syntax doc on the dotCMS site: https://dotcms.com/docs/latest/content-search-syntax.

Hope this helps!